# Consulta sobre query SQL

Tags: mysql, sql

Estoy intentando darle un alias a la devolución de la siguiente consulta:

```
SELECT COUNT (*) [columna] 
FROM [tabla] 
WHERE [columna] = ' '
```

Pero probando con la siguiente consulta no obtengo el resultado buscado:

```
SELECT COUNT (*) [columna] AS Cuenta
FROM [tabla] 
WHERE [columna] = ' '
```

¿Algún indicio de porque no estaría funcionando mi consulta?

¡Saludos a todos!

Comment: Qué resultado obtienes? qué resultado esperas?

Comment: En la primera consulta, a  `count(*)` le estás poniendo como alias `[columna]`, en la segunda tienes un error de sintaxis, pues intentas ponerle otro alias a la misma columna. Dado que no explicas lo que pretendes obtener, resulta muy difícil decir cual sería la sintaxis correcta para tu consulta.

Answer (score 3):

Creo que el problema es el nombre de la columna, al poner COUNT(*), el asterisco representa toda la fila, por lo que te cuenta el número de registros total de la tabla.

```
SELECT COUNT (*) AS Cuenta
FROM [tabla] 
WHERE [columna] = '
```

No se si lo que quieres es la cuenta de filas, espero que te sirva

Un saludo

Comment: Funcionó excelente, ¡muchísimas gracias!